# Write a program to print only even numbers between 6 and 16 using events

Tags: vb.net

I am new to programming as you can see. I need to add an event. We are learning about events and there is really no help and I have tried using the internet for hours. I just want to learn. Thanks ahead of time.

```
Module Modulel

Public Event PrintThis(ByVal val as Integer)

SubMain()

Dim number as Integer = 6
While number <= 16
// PRINT Goes here .. ??? Not sure if right or code
number = number + 2
End While
```

Comment: What type of event do you want to use? A Button.Click event?

Comment: Did the instructor provide material on the "Events" to be used? (Events are usually invoked in *reaction* to some external input or change; using one here is .. somewhat silly. But if the goal is just "to fill in the code", then "invoke the PrintThis event"; generally a guard is used against Empty events.)

Comment: He did not tell us a specific event just one like I put in my code,

Comment: It probably does not make since. I was trying to incorporate it into the code I already had written somehow. This if I could

Comment: An event can be declared in this way:

Accessspecifier Event evtName(parameter)

In the above syntax, Access specifier specifies the scope of the event. It may be public protected or private. Event is the keyword to declare the event. evtName is the name of the event and parameter are values passed to functions that handles the event.

Comment: This is some of what is on my cyber class material about events. There are no examples of coding with these kinds of events.

Answer (score 0):

Below link will give you clear understanding of Events.
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/custom-events-in-vb.net-2005/.

Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. You need to use [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to add the Method that will respond to your event when you call [RaiseEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwd3bwed%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
Module Module1
    Public Event PrintThis(ByVal val As Integer)
    Sub Main()

        AddHandler PrintThis, AddressOf PrintThisMethod
        Dim number As Integer = 6
        While number <= 16
            RaiseEvent PrintThis(number)
            number = number + 2
        End While
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintThisMethod(val As Integer)
        Console.WriteLine(val)
    End Sub

End Module
```